# Store Image file in Binary data in mongoose schema and Display image in html form

Tags: javascript, image, mongodb, express, schema

I am using Express, Node.js, and Mongodb to create the webpage that uploads and displays the image file.

I saved the binary of image in mongodb using schema.

Here is my little bit of code in index.js and db.js..

```
var Post = mongoose.Schema({
   image: {data: Buffer, contentType: String}
});

var post= new Post({ });
post.image.data=fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
post.image.contentType='image/png';
```

and here is the part of mongo shell after I submitted image file and searched for post, and its image field

```
"image:     {"data:BinData(0,"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUE....(I
just cut off the rest of the code.. cuz it was too long)          
rkJggg=="), 
"contentType" : "image/png" }
```

so it seemed like it's successfully saving the binary data of image file in mogngodb,

**but my problem is how to display the image on the webpage now using binary data. How do I convert binary buffer data to create image tag??**

```
<img src= "data:{{image.contentType}};base64,{{image.data}}">
```

I tried this, but it gives me an error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

Could you guys please let me know how do I solve this??
I will really appreciate for your help :(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to convert buffer data to base64. You can do it in back-end or front-end it does not matter. Just use `yourBufferData.toString('base64')`. Then you can use it.

However, I would suggest another way to store images instead of storing binary data. Assuming you use nodejs. You can create image in a repository with that binary data using `fs.writeFile` method. Then you can store that image path in record (db). AFter that, just put the file path into ng-src="file path which you saved". Here is the example which I use:

```
var path = 'upload/profiles/' +req.body.userId + '_profile.jpg';
      fs.writeFile(path, base64data, function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        User.findByIdAndUpdate({
          _id: req.body.userId
        }, {
          $set: {
            profileImg: 'upload/profiles/' +req.body.userId + '_profile.jpg'
          }
        }, function(err, user) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          return res.send(user);
        });
      });

  <img ng-src="savedpath">
```

Comment: Hey @semih Can you tell me a way to store my base64 image string in db directly, instead of file path ?

Comment: Good idea, but when your Nodejs API is behind a load balancer, it's usually not a good idea to store anything on the file system.

Comment: This isn't a good idea.  If you were to take this approach, you'd be better off sticking the file in an Amazon S3 bucket or some other sort of file serving system and then serving the URL for it.  Writing to the local file system only works with a single node, and can lead to the entire system going down for lack of disk space if you don't have proper controls in place.