# How to display image stored as binary data in MongoDB using Mustache in Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mustache

I have an image (png) file stored in my MongoDB as binary data. My MongoDB schema looks like below :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
ImageSchema = new Schema (
{ title : String,
  picture: { content: Buffer, contentType: String }
}
);
```

The mustache code looks like below:

```
var template = "{{picture.content}} <h1>{{title}}</h1>";
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, imageObject);
$('#target').html(rendered);
```

The data in MongoDB looks like below, it has been shortened as it is too long:

```
 "picture" : {
                "contentType" : "image/png",
                "content" : BinData(0,"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg ...")
             }
```

Below is how I am storing it into MongoDB using multer :

```
dbmodel.findOne(req.params.title, function(err, ) {
 records.picture.content = fs.readFileSync(req.files.path);
        records.picture.contentType = 'image/png';
        records.save(function (err) {
          if(!err) {
            res.send("Image is saved into MongoDB");

          } else {
            res.send(400).send();
          }
 })
```

What is the way to convert this binary data to image and especially fit it into the Mustache template for display ?  Also please let me know if the image needs to be saved in some other way and how for easier display using Mustache.

Thanks.

Comment: well you can't render binary data to an image like that instead just create an route for rendering images from binary data returning proper http headers use the image src attribute to point to the route. I believe though that storing images like that will stress your server a lot, use some kind of storage way that stores to files and also handles caching and stuff.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix Thanks for your reply, I have added some more code about how am I saving it into MongoDB, could you please put some example code to explain your idea ?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix As an alternative way  I am using the fs.writeFile code from this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/37091088/6038082 , could you please tell me what should I put in place of base64data as the second argument to writeFile ?

Comment: If anybody has a working code to save the actual image into MongoDB so as to render it later using Mustache , please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Convert binary data into image by converting it to a URL and then feeding to src of `<img>` tag-

```
var template="<img src={{{`data:image/png;base64,${picture.content}`}}}/> <h1>{{title}}</h1>";
```