# Display binary image from MongoDB in React through Express server

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, base64, binary-image

I have a set of binary images stored in MongoDb:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Bwk.png)

```
Binary('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtcwIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH3AABABkAAwApADlh...', 0)
```

I get it with mongoose in Express server and send through API endpoint:

```
App.get("/getImages", function(req,res){
Picture.find({},function(err,foundImages){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(409).send(err);
    }else{
        res.status(200).send(foundImages);
    }
});
```

On the front end I make a call to that point from React:

```
useEffect(() => {

    fetch("/getImages", {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => { return response.json() })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        setData(result);
    })

}, []);
```

But when I do console.log of one of the images, I get a long array of integers from 0 to 255 (853514 items).

```
data: (853514) [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 72, 0, 72, 0, 0, 255, 226, 2, 28, 73, 67, 67, 95, 80, 82, 79, 70, 73, 76, 6...
```

I'm trying to display that image in img tag following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326609/how-to-display-image-stored-as-binary-data-in-mongodb-using-mustache-in-node-js) post.
I've tried various options, but the latest one is this:

```
function Gallery(props) {
console.log(props.data.img);
let source = props.data.img.data;
console.log(source);
return (
    <figure className="gallery__item gallery__item--5">
        <img src={`data:image/jpg;base64,${source}`} alt="Gallery item 5" className="gallery__img"/>
        <figcaption className="gallery__item--descr">
            <span className="gallery__item--descr-title">{props.data.title}</span>
            <span className="gallery__item--descr-text">{props.data.description}</span>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
);
```

}

export default Gallery;

It doesn't show the image. In the browser in the console it shows `data:image/jpg;base64,[object Object]:1 GET data:image/jpg;base64,[object Object] net::ERR_INVALID_URL`

It looks like it is trying to send a request somewhere.

Could you please explain what is going on here? I don't even know what to google.

Comment: In general, databases aren't great for storing images. It is better to use a cdn. You can store asset ids in your database. Then generate urls that point to your images on the cdn. It will be much faster for the user and much less load on your server. :)

Comment: Thank you for advice. I'll try to figure out how Firebase works.

Comment: @Jack_loc Hi, did you figure it out eventually?